# Polynomials proof

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $f$ and $g$ be nonzero polynomials over a field $F$. If $g|f$

How can I prove that

${\rm deg}(g) \leq {\rm deg}(f)$

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If grd(f) means degree of f, how about using grd(fg) = grd(f) + grd(g)?

Comment: Yes! It means degree

Comment: According to https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Degree_of_Product_of_Polynomials_over_Ring
, the equation(degree of multiplication) doesn't hold on general Ring, but it holds on integral domains. As every field is an integral domain, I hope we can use it.

Comment: I'll try to use it, thanks!

Comment: Hint: $g\mid f$ means, $\exists$ a polynomial $p$ such that $g\cdot p=f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we are working over the integral domain. As $g$ divide $f$ imply that
$$ f = k g\tag{*} $$
for some nonzero polynomial $k$ that imply that
$ deg (f ) = deg(k) + deg(g)$ where $deg(k)\geq 0$.
Imply your statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!